# Force crash/exception on NaN assignment in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, debugging, clang, nan

I often have subtle bugs or crashes in my C/C++ program when my code is dealing with NaN floats. Usually when this happens the program crashes in some unexpected place, for example at an array indexing like this `array[int(some_float) - 1]`. I then have to spend a lot of time chasing the reason for such a problem, identifying that `some_float` is NaN and looking at all the places where it might have been assigned to NaN.

Is there a way to force the compiler to crash early at exact moment and place where it assigned something to NaN? Since even assigning to NaN is a failed state for my program.

Comment: please tag the langauge you are using only.

Comment: and why tag `clang` but not mention it in the question? Are you bound to using the clang compiler?

Comment: irrespective of your current issue, this `array[int(some_float) - 1]` needs to be fixed, otherwise you will continue to run into various other issues. Calling this "unexpected place" is a big understatement. Its nasal demons lurking around the corner just waiting to get out

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai I'm currently bound to clang, yes, but I don't know if the solution is compiler-specific.

Comment: mention that in the question. Tags are to summarize what you wrote in the quesiton not for additional info

Comment: AFAIK, float and double are builtin types, even in C++. So overwriting the assignment operator is probably not an option. IMHO, if you want to control the assigned value, your best options are: 1. in C stop using direct assignment but use a custom function to  assign double and float variables 2. in C++ you can use a custom class wrapping a float or double and provide custom constructors and assignment operators. That way, you will have a place to add consistent tests.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai I don't think something like `array[int(some_float) - 1]` is inherently bad in all circumstances. When working with spatial hash grid I don't think you can get away without it.

Comment: make it `array[ my_safe_cast_to_int(some_float) -1]` and we can agree. But a plain c-style cast from `float` to `int` is too dangerous. Suppose you "know" the value is >= 1, but then it happens that it is `0.99999999` and it all goes booom

Comment: If it happens that you get `NaN` while you calculate `some_float`, can you really be sure that you cannot get numbers that are negative or just too large for the array? Some range check prior to using it as index would be useful.

Comment: yes, just like Gerhardh says, your question shows that you cannot get away *with* it. Dont use a float as array index direclty, if you do you will get problems

Comment: Calculating array indices using floating point operations is a bad habit (regardless of how you subsequently convert it to an integral type).   Better to find an appropriate way to calculate the index using integral types (e.g. avoid using `std::pow()` to raise an integral value to some power).   That said, if using floating point is unavoidable (although, I emphasise, in the vast majority of cases it is avoidable) then catch the error while *calculating* `some_float`, not while later trying to convert it to `int`.